# Finding the equation of a plane by its parametric equations

Tags: analytic-geometry

How can I find the equation of a plane by its parametric equations?

Like this one:

p: x = h + t
   y = -1 + 2h - 3t
   z = -3 + h - t

The exercise is to see if a given straight (r in this case) is contained in the plan (Pi), as the following photo 
[image]

Could you guys please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $$x-2=t,\frac{y+2}{2}=t,z+3=t$$ where $t$ is a real number.
So we have $$[x,y,z]=[2,-2,-3]+t[1,2,1]$$
That is true, since we have
$$t+2-2=\frac{2t-2}{2}=t-3+3=t$$.True!

Comment: I did that, then I found that: 
x = t + 2;
y = 2t - 2;
z = t -3;

Comment: Now, to see if the straight is contained in the given plan, I would have to replace that in the plan's equation, wouldn't I?

Comment: Where is your given plane?

Comment: It is π (It is in the photo)

Comment: I got it, see the lines from me!

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it! Lemme ask a silly question: Let's say that I got the plan's equation, in order to a straight  be contained in the plan, I select two points in this straight and I replace those points in the plan's equation, if the equation evaluates to zero in the two given points coordinates, it is true to be said that the straight is contained in the plan, right? It would also be a possible solution, wouldn't it?